# Set the culture of the visual studio test runner

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nunit

I have CountryManager class with a method that returns all countries in the EU. Each country has a two-letter code(hard-coded) and a name that comes from a resource file. I'd like to create a unit test that checks if CountryManager returns a country and sets its name in German.

```
public class CountryManager
{
        public IEnumerable<Country> GetEUCountries()
        {
            yield return new Country("fr", Resources.France);
            yield return new Country("de", Resources.Germany);
            //all other EU countries
        }
    }
```

I tried to create the following NUnit test:

```
    [TestCase("fr", Resources.France)]
    [TestCase("de", Resources.Germany)]
    public void GetEUCountries_ContainsACountry(string code, string name)
    {
        var countryManger = new CountryManager();
        var countries = countryManger.GetEUCountries();
        Assert.IsNotNull(
            countries.SingleOrDefault(c=>c.Code == code && c.Name == name)
            );
    }
```

However, that resulted in an error as Resources.France is not a compile-time constant. I refactored my code to use a static object as a data source like that:

```
static object[][] CountriesSource = new object[][]
    {
        new object[] {"fr", Resources.France },
        new object[] {"de", Resources.Germany}
    };

    [TestCaseSource(nameof(CountriesSource))]
    public void GetEUCountries_ContainsACountry(string code, string name)
```

That worked as expected but another think I wanted to test was that the names were correct in German. NUnit supports the SetCulture and SetUICulture attributes which can be used on method, class or assembly level. However, none of them worked for me - in test explorer I always got the English strings:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UuXVI.png)

The only way I found to make the test explorer discover and run the tests in German is by refactoring my TestCaseSource into a property and setting the culture in the getter:

```
static object[][] CountriesSource
    {
        get {
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de");
            return new object[][]
            {
                new object[] {"fr", Resources.France },
                new object[] {"de", Resources.Germany}
            };
     }
    }

    [TestCaseSource(nameof(CountriesSource))]
```

The result was that TestExplorer displayed and ran the tests correctly in German:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMfBN.png)

However, this is a nasty workaround that I need to apply in many places(all the static test cases sources in all the unit tests projects). Is there a way to set the culture of TestRunner globally (when I debug I see it gets my local culture, ideally I would be able to change it to German)?